# How can I write: if element is selected, don't click Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium

In this link, the product color is selected (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32910109818.html). I try to write with the code below; if element is selected don't click, if not selected click.

However, when the page opens, X520 is selected. The code below behaves as if it is not selected. Do you have a suggestion about this? Where am I doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32910109818.html"
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

color= "X520"
color1= browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='sku-property-text']//*[text()="+"'"+color+"'"+"]").is_selected()
if color1== False:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='sku-property-text']//*[text()="+"'"+color+"'"+"]").click()
else:
    print("no action taken")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse color like below, and wrape the code inside try-except clause

You can try with the below code :

```
color= "X520"
try:
   if broswer.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[@class='sku-property-text']//*[text()= '{color}']").is_selected():
      print("already selected")
   else:
       print("It's not selected, so bot is going to click")
       broswer.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[@class='sku-property-text']//*[text()= '{color}']").click()
       print("Clicked")
except:
    print("Something is wrong.")
    pass
```

Comment: I second this. The above code should do the magic.

Comment: @cruisepandey Thank you for the answer. Your code is much more useful. However, even though element(X520) is selected, the program says "Something is wrong." gives the output. I couldn't understand the reason for the error

Comment: I can't access this URL, are you sure it's correct ?

Comment: Yes, i can open; https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32910109818.html. 
Can you check again? Thank you